# Properly hide `<div>` with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, click, hide

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="alert-message success">
  <a class="close" style="display: none; ">×</a>
  <p>Authenticated as Zach.</p>
</div>
```

And the following jQuery:

```
$('.close').click(function(){
  $('.alert-message success').hide('slow');
});
```

Is there something fundamentally wrong about hiding a `<div>`?  If I hide `.close` instead, there is no problem.  I'm not sure why this isn't working though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It needs to be:

```
$('.close').click(function(){
  $('.alert-message.success').hide('slow');
});
```

With `$('.alert-message success')`, you're asking JQuery to look for a div class `.success` inside a separate div class `alert-message`.

Answer (score 2):

The selector is invalid. Remove "success" and it should be GTG.

Check the JSFiddle to confirm: http://jsfiddle.net/bP6g4/

Comment: Because of the space character?

Comment: Because you are missing the "." before "success". It isn't necessary to include the entire class list to select the proper element. in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Always prefer **not to** use Spaces in names. Prefer 'underscore' or 'camelCase'. Space acts as a delimiter.

When you are saying `$('.alert-message success')` jQuery interprets that there is an **HTML Element** called 'success' (ie `<success>`) inside 'alert-message' class, lets hide that element. Hence it does not give proper output even though code is right.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely agree.  The only reason that space character is in there is because I was utilizing twitter's [new bootstrap toolkit](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) lol.  Should have realized though.